# How can i do for run an app when ubuntu start?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Hi i tried in several ways to launch firefox by example at the beginning,  obviously my machine enters automatically to ubuntu without ask for user or password, so i made a script like that :  firefox url.         And i put this script on cron with the parameter : @reboot + path of my script but it doesn't works, because firefox is not launched,  is not only firefox i need to will able to launch as well gedit when ubuntu start, i hope that can i help me whit this.

By the way i have ubuntu 14.04

Thanks

Comment: open startup applications (via dash) and add firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Startup Applications via dash

[image: Go to Startup Applications via dash]

There, add firefox ...

[image: There, add firefox ...]

You can specify the URL to open by writing the command:

```
firefox URL
```

This will open URL in the browser. No script needed...

Comment: But what about if i have a dhcp ip and i need to specify it to firefox every time at start ubuntu?

Comment: You might need to extract it from the content of either `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases`, `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`,  `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` or a file with a similar name in similar location. You can add the command that runs he script to startup applications.

Comment: And after extract it how can i specific it with firefox knowing that the ip will change after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a script for this.
Ubuntu has a GUI for managing startup applications called "startup applications"

1. Click the Search button at the top of the Unity bar
2. Search for "Startup applications" and press enter
3. In the GUI you can press "add" and enter a custom command of your choice

Also look at existing entries to see how it is done.

Comment: Yes i know that, but the thing with firefox is that i need to launch at the beginning with a specific address, for that reason i think that inneed a script for that

Comment: And to be specific this adresss will change after each reboot, is the ip address

Comment: Do you mean to open the ip address of the local computer? Then you don/t need to find that using a script, you can simply use http://localhost/ which always points to the local machine. The argument you can also specify in the startup applications gui.